# Validating a yum repository for dependencies

Tags: rpm, yum, rhel5

I am trying to create a custom rhel5.5 repository for my usage and I am having a hard time validating if I have all the dependencies for every package in my repository.

What I would want to do is do a yum install in dry run on every package in my repository to see if all the dependencies are available.

Is there an easy way to do that?

---

EDIT
I've found the answer.
Download yum-utils

> yum install yum-utils

and do a repoclosure

> repoclosure

It will find all missing dependencies of the repositories that you have set in your /etc/yum.repo.d/*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yum install yum-utils

and do a repoclosure

repoclosure

It will find all missing dependencies of the repositories that you have set in your /etc/yum.repo.d/*

Comment: what if your repos are in a non-default location? say /etc/yum-test.repo.d/ ?